# Computing pfaffian of a skew-symmetric matrix

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to obtain pfaffian of a 50×50 skew-symmetric matrix in python programming language. I studied a code for a similar purpose that they used [wimmer](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/2331130.2331138)'s package for computing this quantity. However,they used a for loop which produces matrices with different even dimensions each time(from 2×2 to 50×50 dimension) and compute the pfaffian quantity for each of them and sum over all of them to obtain the pfaffian of the 50*50 matrix.

```
R=25
A = 0+0j
for r in range(1,R+1):
    M1 = np.zeros((2*r,2*r),dtype = "complex_")

    for k1 in range(1,n+1):
      
        for i1 in range(2*r-1):
            for j1 in range(i1+1,2*r):
                if i1%2 ==0:                    
                    if j1%2 ==0:
                        M1[i1][j1] = M1[i1][j1] + sin(k1*(i1-j1))               
                        M1[j1][i1] = -M1[i1][j1]
                    else:
                        M1[i1][j1] =  M1[i1][j1] + cos(k1*(i1-j1))                
                        M1[j1][i1] = -M1[i1][j1]                      
                else:
                    if j1%2 ==0:
                        M1[i1][j1] =  M1[i1][j1] - cos(k1*(i1-j1))                   
                        M1[j1][i1] = -M1[i1][j1]
                    else:
                        M1[i1][j1] =  M1[i1][j1] +  sin(k*(i1-j1))                
                        M1[j1][i1] = -M1[i1][j1]                                                        

    A = A + pf.pfaffian(M1)

FinalM = A.real
M.append(FinalM)
```

I cannot understand why they did this way.Can anyone give me some insight into this?

Comment: I can't understand either

Comment: Thanks Bob, maybe it's more a mathematical problem

Comment: As far as I can see the sum of pfafians can only be a sum of pfafians. If you took the product of pfafians you could at least say that it corresponds to the pfafian of the product.

Comment: yeah but i cannot understand why they consider one whole matric to sum of different matrices with different dimensions. while the purpose of their work was to find the pfaffian of a matrix with 50*50 dimension